# Sorting lines in a file by a numeric value burried inside

Tags: sort

I'm writing a Bash script to test USB flash memory for errors using `f3` tool.
I have text like this (created by grepping logs from `f3read` program):

```
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdf.log:Data LOST: 4.00 KB (8 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdi.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdj.log:Data LOST: 2.35 MB (4822 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdn.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdo.log:Data LOST: 4.00 KB (8 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdp.log:Data LOST: 4.00 KB (8 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdq.log:Data LOST: 2.00 KB (4 sectors)
2017-10-25_14:37:03/sdb.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-25_14:37:03/sdc.log:Data LOST: 3.00 KB (6 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdd.log:Data LOST: 3.00 KB (6 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sde.log:Data LOST: 2.00 KB (4 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdf.log:Data LOST: 3.00 KB (6 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdg.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdh.log:Data LOST: 611.29 MB (1251918 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdi.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdl.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdo.log:Data LOST: 3.00 KB (6 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdp.log:Data LOST: 2.00 KB (4 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdq.log:Data LOST: 414.60 MB (849106 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdr.log:Data LOST: 65.29 MB (133712 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sds.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
```

I would like to sort the lines by the number of bad sectors noted at the end of the line. I tried using `sort`, but I don't know how to use it's `--key` option to make it do what I want.

I cannot cut the lines first, becasue I need the drive name (sda, sdb, etc) to be then extracted for a report.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `sort -V` if that option is available

> -V, --version-sort
>
> natural sort of (version) numbers within text

```
$ <cmd> | sort -k5,5V
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdq.log:Data LOST: 2.00 KB (4 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sde.log:Data LOST: 2.00 KB (4 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdp.log:Data LOST: 2.00 KB (4 sectors)
2017-10-25_14:37:03/sdc.log:Data LOST: 3.00 KB (6 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdd.log:Data LOST: 3.00 KB (6 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdf.log:Data LOST: 3.00 KB (6 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdo.log:Data LOST: 3.00 KB (6 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdf.log:Data LOST: 4.00 KB (8 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdo.log:Data LOST: 4.00 KB (8 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdp.log:Data LOST: 4.00 KB (8 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdi.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdn.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-25_14:37:03/sdb.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sds.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdg.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdi.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdl.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdj.log:Data LOST: 2.35 MB (4822 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdr.log:Data LOST: 65.29 MB (133712 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdq.log:Data LOST: 414.60 MB (849106 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdh.log:Data LOST: 611.29 MB (1251918 sectors)
```

Answer (score 10):

POSIXly, you can do:

```
sort -t '(' -k2n < file
```

That is set the field separator to `(` and sort  on the second field (or rather the portion of the line starting with the second field) numerically.

Alternatively, you could keep the default field separator (the transition from a non-blank to a blank) where the 5<sup>th</sup> field would be like `" (12"` and use:

```
sort -k5.3n < file
```

(that is, sort numerically on the portion of the line starting with the 3<sup>rd</sup> character of the 5<sup>th</sup> field).

For ties, the last-resort sorting order comes into play, and that's lexical comparison of the full line (which conveniently here will give you a chronological order).

If you wanted to sort ties on drive name instead, you could use:

```
sort -t '(' -k2n -k1.21
```

(second key being the portion of line starting with the 21<sup>st</sup> character, lexical comparison)

Comment: Why is it `sort < file` rather than just `sort file`?

Comment: @dessert, why `sort file` rather than just `sort < file`? The shell can open the file, no need to pass it to `sort`. See also [When should I use input redirection?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759)

Answer (score 3):

I've found it.

```
sort -n -t '(' -k2V
```

`-n` tells sort to read numeric values in the strings

`-t '('` tells it to use `(` character as field delimiter. Becasue the word *sectors)* is always the same later on it won't affect the sorting order.

`-k2V` defines a custom key, using the second column - text after first `(` character - for sorting.

Comment: Note that you don't need the (GNU-specific) `V` flag here (which by the way makes `-n` redundant). That would be useful if the key didn't start with a digit like in @sundeep's approach where the key starts with `" ("`. `V` is for _version sort_ where  `v3.4` sorts before `v3.20` (but after `u5` or `V5`) which are not numbers and would be considered as 0 with the `n` flag. Same for `" (2"` vs `" (10"`.

Answer (score 3):

If your standard sort version does not offer option -V, then you might be able to use an alternate sorting program msort. It allows the use of a *hybrid* option:
*Hybrid comparison is like lexicographic comparison except for the fact that strings of digits are treated as numbers.*

So a snippet like this:

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }
pl " Input data file $FILE:"
tail -v $FILE

pl " Expected output:"
tail -v $E

pl " Results:"
msort -q -j -l -n 5,5 -c hybrid $FILE |
tail -v
```

produces this:

```
-----
 Input data file data1:
==> data1 <==
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdf.log:Data LOST: 3.00 KB (6 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdg.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdh.log:Data LOST: 611.29 MB (1251918 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdi.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdl.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdo.log:Data LOST: 3.00 KB (6 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdp.log:Data LOST: 2.00 KB (4 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdq.log:Data LOST: 414.60 MB (849106 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdr.log:Data LOST: 65.29 MB (133712 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sds.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)

-----
 Expected output:
==> expected-output1 <==
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdn.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-25_14:37:03/sdb.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sds.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdg.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdi.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdl.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdj.log:Data LOST: 2.35 MB (4822 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdr.log:Data LOST: 65.29 MB (133712 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdq.log:Data LOST: 414.60 MB (849106 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdh.log:Data LOST: 611.29 MB (1251918 sectors)

-----
 Results:
==> standard input <==
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdi.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdn.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-25_14:37:03/sdb.log:Data LOST: 5.00 KB (10 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdi.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdl.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdg.log:Data LOST: 6.00 KB (12 sectors)
2017-10-25_09:30:22/sdj.log:Data LOST: 2.35 MB (4822 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdr.log:Data LOST: 65.29 MB (133712 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdq.log:Data LOST: 414.60 MB (849106 sectors)
2017-10-26_09:17:59/sdh.log:Data LOST: 611.29 MB (1251918 sectors)
```

Some details for msort:

```
msort   sort records in complex ways (man)
Path    : /usr/bin/msort
Version : 8.53
Type    : ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYS ...)
Help    : probably available with -h,--help
Repo    : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
Home    : http://www.billposer.org/Software/msort.html (pm)
```

On a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Comment: I managed to do it with `sort`, even without the `-V` option, and `msort` is not by default installed on Linux Mint 18.2. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi. OK, good to see that you solved it, but keep msort in mind for tasks that sort might not be able to handle, and it's available at least on systems like Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca ... cheers

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more flexible solution extracts the sector count, duplicates it at the beginning of the line, sorts, and finally removes the duplicated part again:

```sh
sed 's/^.*(\([0-9]\{1,\} \)sectors)$/\1&/' |
  sort -n |
  cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

This solution is more flexible because it works for arbitrary patterns that identify the sort key in each record.